# Rename command with non-existing target directory

Tags: files, perl, rename

I'm trying to group files automatically into subdirectories using a command like this:

```
$ rename 's/(.)(.)(.+)/$1\/$2\/$1$2$3/' *.*
```

A dry run with the `-n` parameter shows me what I want:

> ```
> test.jpg renamed as t/e/test.jpg
> ```

But the actual renaming fails with

> ```
> Can't rename test.jpg t/e/test.jpg: No such file or directory
> ```

because the subdirectories do not exist yet.

How can I achieve this without creating all subdirectories manually beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is difference between renaming and moving to somewhere. 
In this case the easiest way (in modern `bash`) is to loop through all files:

```
for f in *.*
do
    d=${f::1}/${f:1:1}
    [ -d "$d" ] || mkdir -p "$d"
    mv "$f" "$d"
done
```

#### Explanation

This makes use of the lesser known "Parameter Expansion / Substring Expansion" feature of bash.

> `${var:offset:length}`
>
> Expands to up to *`length`* characters of the value of *`var`*
> starting at the character specified by *`offset`*.

.  <sup>[Slightly paraphrased from [bash(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION).]</sup>

I don't see where this is documented, but, *`offset`* is zero-based,
so `0` is the first character and `1` is the second. 
If *`offset`* is null (missing), it is taken to be zero.

Comment: I had to change `/${f:2}` to `/${f}` but then it works like a charm. Thanks for pointing out the alternative!

Comment: @fschmengler I miss that you wants to have full file's name not remaining part. See edited.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of [Costas’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186771/80216),

```bash
for f in *.*
do
    if [ "${f:0:1}" = . ]  ||  [ "${f:1:1}" = . ]
    then
        printf 'Cannot handle "%s"\n' "$f"
    else
        d=${f:0:1}/${f:1:1}
        if ! { [ -d "$d" ] || mkdir -p "$d"  &&  mv "$f" "$d"; }
        then
            break
        fi
    fi
done
```

- I added the (first) `if`
  to handle filenames like `M.Butterfly.jpg` and `Q.jpg`,
  because you can’t (really) make directories like `M/.` and `Q/.`. 
  Likewise, `.Dragon.mp4`
  would try to create a directory called `./D`.<sup>1</sup>
- I added the `&&` (between the `mkdir` and the `mv`) so,
  if the `mkdir` fails,
  we don’t try to move the file into the non-existent directory.
- I added the second `if` because,
  if something fails, it makes sense for the script to terminate
  and let the user figure out (and fix) what’s wrong. 
  (For example, what if you accidentally run the script in a directory
  where you don’t have write permission, or the file system is full
  and so you cannot create the new subdirectories?)

  I could have written this as

  ```
  [ -d "$d" ] || mkdir -p "$d"  &&  mv "$f" "$d  ||  break
  ```

  but these `&&`/`||` sequences get confusing very quickly.

Another variation:

```bash
for f in *.*
do
    if [ "${f:0:1}" = . ]  ||  [ "${f:1:1}" = . ]
    then
        printf 'Cannot handle "%s"\n' "$f"
    else
        d=${f:0:1}/${f:1:1}
        if ! { [ -d "$d" ] || mkdir -p "$d"; }          # Note: no "mv" command in the loop.
        then
            break
        fi
    fi
done
rename 's/(.)(.)(.+)/$1\/$2\/$1$2$3/' *.*
```

This has the advantage that it invokes `rename` only once
instead of invoking `mv` a thousand times. 
It has a couple of drawbacks:

- files like `M.Butterfly.jpg` and `Q.jpg` get passed to `rename`.
- `rename` gets run even if `mkdir` fails. 
  (This is probably easy to fix. 
  One way would be to replace the `break` with `exit`,
  but that seems inelegant.)

I don’t have the same version of `rename` as you,
but I tried `mv M.Butterfly.jpg M/.`,
and it simply moved `M.Butterfly.jpg` into the directory `M`. 
So, if you use my second solution, when you list the directory `M`,
you will see subdirectories `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, etc., (containing files
like `Many.jpg`, `Memorable.jpg`, `Minnesota.jpg`, `Moments.jpg`, etc.)
and a few plain files (like `M.Butterfly.jpg`). 
You can then deal with them as you please. 
________________ 
<sup>1</sup> Actually, the commands will succeed,
but they will create directories called `M`, `Q` and `D`,
which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done entirely witin the `rename` script, because `rename` allows the use of **any** perl code, it's not limited to just simple `s///` operators.

The following works in the simple case that all files to be renamed are in the current directory and are passed to `rename` directly on the command-line without a `./` prefix (which is generally not a good idea because of the potential for filenames beginning with `-` which could be interpreted as command-line options for `rename`).

It won't work if the filenames include a directory prefix, e.g. they are passed to `rename` via `find` or as `./*.*`.

```
$ touch test.jpg test.txt
$ rename -n 'my ($a, $b) = (/(.)(.)/);
             mkdir $a unless -e $a;
             mkdir "$a/$b" unless -e "$a/$b";
             if (-e "$a/$b" && ! -d "$a/$b") {
               print STDERR "$_: $a/$b exists but is not a directory!\n";
             } else {;
               s/(.)(.)(.+)/$1\/$2\/$1$2$3/;
             }' *.*
rename(test.jpg, t/e/test.jpg)
rename(test.txt, t/e/test.txt)
```

A better version could use the [File::Basename](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Basename) and [File::Path](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Path) modules, both of which are included with perl.

```
$ rename -n 'use File::Basename;
             use File::Path qw(make_path);

             my ($bn, $dn) = fileparse($_);
             my ($a, $b) = ($bn =~ /(.)(.)/);
             make_path("$dn$a/$b", { verbose => 1 });
             $_ = "$dn$a/$b/$bn"' ./*.*
mkdir ./t
mkdir ./t/e
rename(./test.jpg, ./t/e/test.jpg)
rename(./test.txt, ./t/e/test.txt)
```

This will create the two sub-directories under each file's original directory.  The `make_path()` function from `File::Path` already checks for existence of the target dir (and treats it as a fatal error if it exists but is not a directory, but you can implement your own error handling if you want it to just print a warning and move on to the next filename).

You could hard-code it to rename all files into a specific directory tree if you wanted to by setting `$dn` to the target top-level directory (you'll still need to use the `File::Basename` module to extract just the basename from the full pathname).